# Running methods on different cores on python

Tags: python, multicore

Is there any easy way to make 2 methods, let's say MethodA() and MethodB() run in 2 different cores? I don't mean 2 different threads. I'm running in Windows, but I'd like to know if it is possible to be platform independent.

edit: And what about

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html
and
[parallel python](http://www.parallelpython.com/content/view/17/31/) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use separate processes (because of the often-mentioned GIL). The [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) is here to help.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from somewhere import A, B 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    procs = [ Process(target=t) for t in (A,B) ]

    for p in procs: 
        p.start()

    for p in procs: 
        p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use CPython (the reference implementation) the answer is **NO** because of the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock). In CPython threads are mainly used when there is much IO to do (one thread waits, another does computation).

Answer (score 0):

In general, running different threads is the best portable way to run on multiple cores.  Of course, in Python, the global interpreter lock makes this a moot point -- only one thread will make progress at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the global interpreter lock, Python programs only ever run one thread at a time. If you want true multicore Python programming, you could look into [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) (which has access to the JVM's threads), or the brilliant [stackless](http://www.stackless.com/), which has [Go](http://golang.org/)-like channels and tasklets.